# Como usar o auto.arima para prever 24 períodos ou mais no R?

Tags: r, data.frame

Fiz uma previsão usando o `auto.arima` onde minha base de dados são valores mensais de jan/2018 a set/2019.

Minha base de treino é de jan/2018 a jun/2019:

```
VL_TR_treino_5S = window(VL_TR_TS_5S, start=c(2018,1), end=c(2019,6))
VL_TR_teste_5S = window(VL_TR_TS_5S, start=c(2019,6))
```

E para aplicar o auto.arima usei outras covariáveis em `xreg`, como exemplo coloquei A, B e C:

```
VL_TR_modelo_5S = auto.arima(VL_TR_treino_5S, xreg = cbind(A,B,C), trace = T, stepwise = T, approximation = T, seasonal = T)
```

E depois usei o forecast usando um período de 24 meses:

```
VL_TR_Prev5S = forecast(VL_TR_modelo_5S, xreg = cbind(A,B,C), h = 24)
```

Porém quando vou visualizar os dados de `VL_TR_Prev5S`, ao invés de me mostrar 24 valores previstos (que seria até dez/2020), me mostra apenas 13 valores que seria de fev/2019 até fev/2020.

```
print(VL_TR_Prev5S)

         Point Forecast   Lo 20   Hi 20
Feb 2019        7649351 7634063 7664639
Mar 2019        8260246 8244958 8275534
Apr 2019        8950091 8934803 8965380
May 2019        8657965 8642677 8673253
Jun 2019        8534740 8519451 8550028
Jul 2019        8349148 8333859 8364436
Aug 2019        7596208 7580920 7611496
Sep 2019        8515507 8500218 8530795
Oct 2019        8103160 8087871 8118448
Nov 2019        8143330 8128042 8158619
Dec 2019        7393488 7378199 7408776
Jan 2020        7007616 6992328 7022905
Feb 2020        6819635 6804346 6834923
```

Quando eu executo o script do `auto.arima`, apesar do algoritmo rodar normalmente, o `r` me deixa o seguinte aviso:

```
Warning message:
The chosen seasonal unit root test encountered an error when testing for the first difference.
From stl(): series is not periodic or has less than two periods
0 seasonal differences will be used. Consider using a different unit root test.
```

Não sei se esse aviso influência na questão, mas optei em mencionar o aviso por desencargo. Pesquisando em alguns fóruns parece que usando covariáveis em `xreg` pode limitar os períodos, mas não sei o porque e também não sei como posso evitar isso. 
Mas enfim, como posso usar o `auto.arima` para prever 24 períodos ou mais?

Comment: Só pra ficar claro para mim: o conjunto de treinamento possui 13 observações e, a partir destas 13 observações, o desejo é projetar 24 períodos no futuro? E, além disso, tu está tentando colocar em cima disso uma sazonalidade (suponho que de 12 meses)?

Comment: Isso mesmo, se eu tiver cometendo algum erro pode me falar.

Comment: Está. A sazonalidade em modelos ARIMA é obtida através de diferenciação do tipo (X_t - X_{t-k}), em que k é o valor da sazonalidade. Como no teu caso são 13 observações e k=12, a série diferenciada sazonalmente vai ter uma observação apenas. Portanto, é impossível aplicar uma sazonalidade como esta nesta quantidade de dados.

Comment: Além disso, trabalho com séries temporais há mais de 15 anos. Nunca vi ninguém utilizar 13 observações para fazer a previsão 24 passos à frente. Mesmo que fosse possível obter resultados a partir disso, eles não seriam confiáveis. Afinal, o que tu basicamente está dizendo é "tenho um ano de comportamento e quero generalizar isso, prevendo os próximos dois anos futuros". Mal comparando, seria como lançar uma moeda uma vez e tentar prever os próximos dois resultados. É possível? Claro que é. Vai ser um modelo confiável? Desconfio que não.

Comment: Obrigado pelos esclarecimentos Marcus Nunes, infelizmente estou de mãos atadas quanto a quantidade de observações, muitas vezes temos que realizar milagres com o que nos é fornecido, pelo menos agora tenho os argumentos necessários.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vou tentar responder o melhor possível às perguntas colocadas na recompensa desta pergunta.

> Entendo que a Ciência de Dados não é perfeita, e se tratando de dados em nosso dia a dia fica eminente que a falta ou a quantidade de dados insuficiente podem ser um problema, ao retratar a pergunta passei entender que não basta criar algoritmos, mas a base de dados é essencial para que o algoritmo funcione.

Excelente observação. Mas gostaria de complementar a frase "basta criar algoritmos, mas a base de dados é essencial para que o algoritmo funcione". Para mim, *funcionar* não significa apenas que o algoritmo convirja para alguma resposta, mas sim que ele convirja para a resposta mais próxima possível da realidade.

> No caso da minha pergunta utilizo uma base de dados pequena que no algoritmo ARIMA não é o suficiente para entender a sazonalidade.

Exato. Toda vez que o modelo ARIMA tiver que considerar sazonalidade (e, assim, se tornar o modelo SARIMA), ele vai perder um determinado número de observações. Isto se deve à diferenciação que é feita na série. [Uma série com sazonalidade k vai perder k observações](https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/lesson/4/4.1).

> Nesses casos a previsão do ARIMA não é confiável?

É sabido que precisamos, no mínimo, p + 1 observações para ajustar um modelo aos nossos dados. Por exemplo, uma reta do tipo y = a*x + b possui dois parâmetros e precisa de ao menos 3 pontos para ser ajustada. Com dois pontos é possível traçar uma reta, mas não é possível calcular o erro padrão dos estimadores. Por isso é necessário ao menos 3 pontos.

De acordo com [Hyndman e Kostento (2007)](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Rob_Hyndman/publication/5055549_Minimum_Sample_Size_Requirements_for_Seasonal_Forecasting_Models/links/0912f50ff0c2aae9e8000000.pdf), são necessárias no mínimo dos mínimos 16 observações para ajustar um modelo `SARIMA (0,1,1)(0,1,1)_{12}`. O teu modelo seria, na pior das hipóteses, um `SARIMA (p,d,q)(P,D,Q)_{12}`, o que dá  `p + q + P + Q + d + m*D + 1` observações, no mínimo dos mínimos, para ele ajustar um modelo aos dados. E um modelo assim seria tão bom quanto uma reta de regressão ajustada a 3 pontos. Ou seja, não serviria para muita coisa.

Além disso, esta conta não considera a variabilidade dos dados. `p + q + P + Q + d + m*D + 1` observações serviriam para modelar um SARIMA com pouca variabilidade. Se os dados forem mal comportados, vão ser necessários ainda mais dados.

Não conheço nenhum estudo que calcule tamanhos amostrais mínimos para estimação em séries temporais, mas a literatura que li da área (e o bom senso dos pesquisadores) sugere algo entre 50 e 100 observações, pelo menos.

> Devo fazer algum tipo de tratamento?

Não. Se fizer questão de usar ARIMA, colete mais dados.

> Ou devo usar outro algoritmo para previsão?

Não. Colete mais dados. Se alguém te disser que é possível utilizar algum modelo ou algoritmo que é capaz de prever dois anos futuros usando observações de um ano apenas, está pessoa estará te enganando. É matematicamente impossível fazer um milagre assim.

Para entender realmente porque é impossível uma previsão assim, sugiro o livro [Brockwell e Davis (1991)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387974296). É um livro antigo, anterior ao surgimento do R, mas é muito forte matematicamente. E a matemática dele não mudou em 28 anos. Do ponto de vista teórico, é o melhor que já li no tratamento de séries temporais. Nele as séries temporais são tratadas como espaços de Hilbert de dimensão `n` e a sua previsão `m` passos à frente é a projeção destes espaços vetoriais de dimensão `n` em espaços de dimensão `n + m`. Lá fica claro porque qualquer método que tente prever muitos passos à frente está fadado ao fracasso. E erro de previsão aumenta muito, impossibilitando qualquer tipo de conclusão aproveitável.

Comment: Obrigado Marcos Nunes pelos esclarecimentos e pela sugestão do material de apoio, esse livro do Brockwell e Davis parece ser muito bom, acredito que é exatamente do que preciso.